# Ехо-бот для Telegram не работает, хотя все проверила

Tags: telegram-bot, telebot, echo

Код проверила в командной строке, там нет замечаний.
Должны ли быть какие-то дополнительные действия между проверкой в cmd и использованием бота?

Главная часть кода (он маленький):

```
@bot.message_handler (func=lambda message: True, content_types=['text'])
def repeat_all_messages(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
      bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

В вашем коде не хватает хендлера(они же декораторы),прочитать про них можно [здесь](https://groosha.gitbook.io/telegram-bot-lessons/extra/pytelegrambotapi_basics).В данном случае `config` это название файла в котором хранится токен вашего бота

```
import config
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.token)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def repeat_all_messages(message): # Название функции не играет никакой роли, в принципе
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
     bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import telebot
from telebot import apihelper

bot = telebot.TeleBot('TOKEN')
apihelper.proxy = {'https': 'socks5h://LOGIN:PASS@IP:1080'}  # если требуется


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def test(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text)


bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```